# R ggplot2: Data in weeks but I want the X-axis in my figure in years

Tags: r, ggplot2

Needed help in this problem. My data is something like this.

```
week   status  dist
0       1       44%
0       2       47%
0       3       9%
1       1       46%
1       2       46%
1       3        8%

young = g_young %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_area(aes(x = week,y=dist, fill = factor(status),
                position = "stack", width = 1),
            stat = "identity", show.legend=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(labels = c("Not listed", "Listed", "Removed", "Transplanted", "Died"),
                    palette = "Blues") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,208,52)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

The data is like this for 4 years (i.e 208 weeks).

The figure that comes out is something like this:
[image: I want this figure with only the X-axis made into years]

However in the above figure I want the X-axis in years with cuts at 0,1,2,3,4.

I tried:

```
g_young$year = cut(g_young$week,
                   breaks=c(-Inf,52,104,156,208),
                   labels = c("1","2","3","4"))

young = g_young %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_area(aes(x =year, y=dist, fill = factor(status),
                position = "stack", width = 1),
            stat = "identity", show.legend=FALSE) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,4,1)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

The figure I get is:

[image: The image I get when I try to use the x=year after cutting the data in weeks into years.]

Any idea how I can use the data as expressed in weeks (so that I can get the smooth curves) but the X-axis in years?

Comment: Create a year column with math? `g_young$year = g_young$week / 52`? Year should still be continuous - not categorical, so no `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: please provide data using `dput`

Comment: @GregorThomas  Works beautifully. Thanks a lot. Simple yet elegant :))))

Comment: tidyverse has `scale_x_date` which allows you to re-scale a date axis into different units. Here is their documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html